# jQuery - replace characters in string, then enforce validation rule

Tags: jquery

Trying to figure out if there's a more succinct or elegant way to write the code below. I'm replacing any slashes in a text box with dashes, then applying a validation rule to the textbox using a custom format string:

```
var bday = $("#home-birthday");
var bdayVal = bday.val();
bday
    .val(bdayVal
        .replace(/\//g, '-')
    )
;
bday
    .rules("add", {
        mydate: true
    })
;
```

I've had a few variations, but figured I'd just throw it up here and see if there's a better way.

Comment: This is more appropriate for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Didn't know about that. Will definitely use that in the future. Thx dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#home-birthday").val(function(i, val) {
    return val.replace(/\//g, '-');
}).rules('add', {mydate: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var bday = $("#home-birthday");
bday.val(
    bday.val().replace(/\//g, '-')
).rules(
    "add", 
    {mydate: true}
);
```